# rsync command in bash script using --from-files giving rsync: link_stat errors

Tags: bash, find, rsync, file-copy

I been getting a lot of `rsync:link stat error` saying the directory does not exist then afterwards it would end up copying all the files in the remote server folder instead of files less than the time specified in the `find` command. Not sure if its a spacing issue or how `bash` interprets the parenthesis. Notice occasionally it works without issue.

Command:

```
rsync --no-perms --ignore-existing -vt --files-from=<(ssh admin@rig700 'find /usr/bin/rig/cache -mmin -720 -type f -exec basename {} \;') admin@rig700:/usr/bin/rig/cache /usr/bin/rig/store
```

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly calling `basename` on each file found by `find`, even if they are found in subdirectories beneath `/usr/bin/rig/cache`. This mean that a file like `/usr/bin/rig/cache/subdir/myfile` would be reported as `myfile` in the list given to the `--files-from=` option of `rsync`.  This file obviously does not exist in `/usr/bin/rig/cache`, so I would expect `rsync` to complain about it.

What you could do instead is to use `-print0` instead of `-exec basename {} \;` with `find`, which would give the *full* paths of all found files, delimited by `\0` (nul) characters.  Then use `--files-from=` with this result, and also use `--from0` to specify that it's a nul-delimited list of pathnames.

Then, as the source path for `rsync`, use `admin@rig700:`.

So, I've suggested two things here:

1. Use `\0` to delimit the pathnames reported by `find` (this is the *only* character that is safe to use for delimiting pathnames on a Unix system, as newlines are allowed in pathnames).
2. Make `find` report the full pathname of files that should be copied, and then use those path as-is with `rsync`.

In the end, your command would be

```
rsync -e 'ssh -q' --no-perms --ignore-existing -vt \
    --from0 --files-from=<(
        ssh -q admin@rig700 'find /usr/bin/rig/cache -mmin -720 -type f -print0'
    ) --no-relative  admin@rig700: /usr/bin/rig/store
```

The `--no-relative` (or `--no-R`) option is needed so that the pathnames read via `--files-from` are taken as absolute pathnames.  Without this option, a pathname such as `/usr/bin/rig/cache/somefile.txt` would have its initial `/` stripped off and be relative to your home directory on the remote host.

I've also used `ssh -q`, both for executing the `find` command on the remote system, and with the `-e` (`--rsh`) option of `rsync`.  I did this because [your remote host seems to otherwise print a welcome banner](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580770/rsync-command-in-bash-script-using-from-files-giving-rsync-link-stat-errors#comment1082407_580864).  This banner confuses `rsync` and so we must disable the printing of it, both for executing the `find` command and for `rsync`.

Summary:

1. Don't run `basename` for the files found by `find`.  Instead get the complete paths for them from the remote system and use `--no-relative` with `rsync`.
2. Make sure that the remote host's welcome banner is not printed.

Comment: I get these strange errors message after the change. Wonder if its because its trying to look for the location of the bash in the remote server Errors:                                                                                                                                                                            rsync: link_ failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat ssh/authorized_keys" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat .bash_logout" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat .bash_profile" failed: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: @Frontier_Brain I realized you will have to also use `--no-relative`. I will update my answer and explain why.

Comment: @Frontier_Brain I don't _quite_ know whether this solves the issue, but the `--no-relative` option needs to be there. If the errors persists, you may want to leg in as ordinary on the remote system and investigate the named files to see if there's something odd about them.

Comment: I think it somewhat worked and it didn't copy all the files(Occasional does copy all the files) but still see these same errors could it have something to do with file permission? The only thing I'm copying are wav files in the folder  rsync: link_stat "//failed/.ssh" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/failed/.ssh" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/failed/.bash_logout" failed: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: @Frontier_Brain The names of the files seems to indicate files that are used when making an `ssh` connection to the remote host, not necessarily files that should be copied. Can you log in with `ssh` as usual to the remote host and investigate these files?

Comment: @Frontier_Brain Does your shell's initialization files _print_ anything to the terminal when you log in?

Comment: When I use ssh or log into the remote host directly I just get the usual  'Pre-authentication banner message from server' Nothing out of the ordinary from what I'm seeing. Wonder if its an issue with the /etc/profile .

Comment: @Frontier_Brain Do you get that banner also for doing simple stuff like `ssh remote ls`?  If so, that would certainly mess up any attempt to `rsync`.

Comment: I did ssh admin@remotehost ls -la and get the banner once followed by the list of files such as .bash_history but doesn't appear when doing other commands afterwards

Comment: @Frontier_Brain Do you also get a banner if you do `ssh -q remote ls`? Or if you create a file called `.hushlogin` in the home directory on the remote host? The welcome banner might be causing an issue for `rsync` (which uses `ssh`).

Comment: I don't get a banner when using that ssh command with the -q.

Comment: @Frontier_Brain See updated answer, and note `ssh -q` and `rsync -e 'ssh -q'`. I will explain these in a little while.

Comment: I get this weird error message when adding the  -e parameters                                                                                                        ssh: Could not resolve hostname q: Name or service not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]

Comment: Looks like it cleared up those error regarding the .bash but the 'rsync: link_stat failed: No such file or directory (2)' errors are still occurring and not copying any files this time. When I add the --no-relative it gives this message instead: 'rsync: change_dir'

Comment: @Frontier_Brain And you're using that exact command, with `--from0` and `-print0`?

Comment: yes, I just see the rsync: link_stat errors with the path of the files I want to copy followed by No such file or directory (2) but it doesn't copy over anything at the end. Last error: rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23)

Comment: @Frontier_Brain Ok, so as the source, use `admin@rig700:/`.

Comment: Its still using the same source path I had before with the admin account It looks something causing the files to not fully transfer even thou its listing the files in those error messages.